# Generalisation of a well known fact: if $a,b,\sqrt[n]a+\sqrt[n]b\in\mathbb Z$, then is it necessary that $\sqrt[n]a,\sqrt[n]b\in\mathbb Z$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I can prove that if $a$ and $b$ are integers such that $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$ is also an integer then $a$ and $b$ are perfect squares.

Is this applicable for $n$-th roots also?

I noticed that for cube roots we must use natural numbers instead of integers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit the post and add your proof for the square root case, and your argument for the use of natural numbers instead of integers in the case of cube roots. The more context the question has, the more likely it is that people get interested in it and post answers. You might like to take a look at the meta post "[How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/229831)".

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3456415/42969.