# $\sqrt{3} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[12]{2})$

Tags: solution-verification, field-theory, galois-theory

Is the following proof correct for showing that $\sqrt{3}\notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[12]{2})$?

If $\xi$ is a primitive twelveth root of $1$, there are 12 morphisms
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[12]{2})\to {\mathbb{\bar Q}}$, given by
$\sqrt[12]{2} \mapsto \xi^j\sqrt[12]{2}$ for $j=0,...,11$.
If $\sqrt3 \in \mathbb Q (\sqrt[12]2)$, then we could write
$$\sqrt{3} = \sum_{k=0}^{11}a_k\sqrt[12]{2^k}.$$
for some rational $a_k$. Now, applying each of the morphisms, we obtain
$$\delta_j\sqrt{3} = \sum_{k=0}^{11}a_k\xi^{jk}\sqrt[12]{2^k}, \ j=0,...,11,$$
where each of the deltas is $\pm 1$.
Adding for all $j,$ we get
$$\sum_{j=0}^{11}\delta_j\sqrt{3} = 12a_0,$$
and since $\sqrt 3$ is irrational, $LHS = a_0 = 0$.
If instead we add only for even $j,$ then we obtain
$$\sum_{\text{even }j}\delta_j\sqrt{3} = 6a_6\sqrt{2};$$ but $\sqrt 3 \notin \mathbb Q (\sqrt 2)$, so again $LHS = a_6 = 0$.
Finally, adding for $j$ a multiple of 4,
$$\sum_{j=0,4,8}\delta_j\sqrt{3} = 3a_3\sqrt[4]{2} + 3a_9\sqrt[4]8.$$
Squaring both sides,
$$3\bigg(\sum_{j=0,4,8}\delta_j\bigg)^2 = 9a_3^2 \sqrt 2 + 18a_9^2 \sqrt 2 + 36a_3a_9.$$
Irrationality of $\sqrt 2$ implies $a_3 = a_9 = 0$, but then
$$\sum_{j=0,4,8}\delta_j = \pm 1 \pm 1 \pm 1 = 0,$$
which is impossible. Thus $\sqrt3 \notin \mathbb Q(\sqrt[12]2)$.

---

I'm a bit suspicious because the only values of $a_k$ used are those
with $k$ a multiple of $3$.

Comment: What's the question?  The header refers to $\sqrt[n] {2}$ but the text seems to set $n=12$.

Comment: Sorry, I only proved it for $n=12$, I've changed the title.

Comment: I'd look at ramification.  Does $3$ ever ramify in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[n] 2)$.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, though I'm not familiar with ramifications.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3990185/72031

Comment: This is not a subject I am deeply familair with, so maybe I am just missing the needed background, but how do "we obtain $\delta_j\sqrt{3} = \sum_{k=0}^{11}a_k\xi^{jk}\sqrt[12]{2^k}, \ j=0,...,11$" from applying each of the morphisms?

Comment: If $\sigma$ is the morphism sending $\sqrt[12] 2$ to $\xi^j\sqrt[12] 2$, then $\sqrt 3$ must go to a root of $x^2-3$ ($\sigma(\sqrt 3) = \pm \sqrt 3$), while $\sigma(\sqrt[12]{2^k})=\sigma(\sqrt[12] 2)^k = (\xi^j\sqrt[12] 2)^k=\xi^{jk}\sqrt[12]{2^k}$, and then using linearity. Do you see anything wrong there?

Comment: Thank you ***paramanand-singh*** for the reference, that's a nice proof of the general case. Now I'm wondering how the condition of primality of p and q could be relaxed for that argument to work, would it be enough that no power of $\alpha$ is a rational multiple of $\beta$, for example $\sqrt[3] 6$ and $\sqrt [3] {12}$? (In the notation of that answer)

Comment: Assuming of course that $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb Q(\beta)$ have degree m and n respectively

Comment: You can also use the following theorem: If $c\in\mathbb {R} \setminus \mathbb {Q} $ and $n$ is a positive integer such that $c^n\in\mathbb {Q} $ then the trace of $c$ as a member of $\mathbb {Q} (c) $ is $0$. Now consider $a=\sqrt{3},b=2^{1/12}$ and apply trace on your first equation (of the question) treating each side as member of $\mathbb {Q} (a, b) $. Repeated application of this idea will give each $a_i=0$.

Comment: You may see the approach in last comment used in a more general setting at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4304716/72031

Comment: I see now that for $\alpha=\sqrt[4]{12},\ \beta=\sqrt[4]{3}$, my conjecture fails since $[\mathbb Q(\alpha):\mathbb Q]=[\mathbb Q(\beta) : \mathbb Q] = 4$ but $[\mathbb Q(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb Q]=8<16$. It looks to me like [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158722/linear-independence-of-nth-roots-over-mathbbq/2432555#2432555) you linked there is the best possible generalization. As a final remark, I think what I did in my proof can be expressed as taking traces first over $\mathbb Q$, then over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$, then over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4] 2)$.

Comment: Just need to use trace map of $\mathbb {Q} (\sqrt{3},2^{1/12})$ over $\mathbb {Q} $. In the proof you will need to make use of the fact that $2^{i/12}\sqrt{3}$ is irrational for each value of $i=0,1,2,\dots,11$.

Comment: The proof by **Paramanand Singh** is simpler and more general; I just wanted to add that it was enough to show $\sqrt 3 \notin \mathbb Q(\sqrt [4] 2)$ and then use the degree theorem. Using the method of proof in the answer, however, this simplification is irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the following

**Lemma**: Let $F\subseteq \mathbb {R} $ be a field and let $a$ be a real number and $m$ a positive integer such that $a\notin F, a^m\in F$. Then the trace $\operatorname {tr} _F^{F(a)} (a) =0$.

Let $a=\sqrt{3},b=\sqrt[12]{2},F=\mathbb {Q} $. Also let degree of extension $F(a, b) $ over $F$ be $n$.

Let us assume that $a\in F(b) $ so that there is a relation of the form $$a=a_0+a_1b+a_2b^2+\dots+a_{11}b^{11}\tag{1}$$ where $a_i\in F$. Note that each of $a, b^i$ with $i=1,2,\dots,11$ is such that it does not lie in $F$ but some power of it lies in $F$ and thus we can apply the lemma to get $$0=na_0+a_1\cdot 0+\dots+a_{11}\cdot 0$$ ie $a_0=0$.

Next we rewrite the equation $(1)$ as $$\frac{a} {b} =a_1+a_2b+\dots+a_{11}b^{10}$$ Applying trace map (and noting that $a/b\notin F$) we again get $0=na_1$ ie $a_1=0$. Continuing in this fashion we get all the $a_i=0$ which is absurd. It follows that $a\notin F(b) $.